# How to judge before the method "performSegueWithIdentifier: sender:"?

Tags: objective-c

I use the storyboard, the need is loginViewController to push another viewController B;
  In the storyboard, I drop the login button to the viewController B, the segue is creat with an identifier.
  Then I write the code. 
  The first I have to judge the password and username. 
  If the password and username is right. The loginViewController to push the viewController B. 
  Then I run the project. I find, the loginViewController is push automatically.
  If I want to judge before the segue. How to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to create the manual segue from source controller to destination controller

In the storyboard right click on the view controller which has the UIButton element [image: Source View controller]

drag from the manual option to the destination view controller and give identifier to the segue.

Later in the button action method first validate the username and password, if they are valid then perform the segue action.

```
@IBAction func buttonTouchupInside(sender: UIButton) {
        //Here validate the username and password..
        if valid {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("your segue identifier", sender: nil)
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps you..! Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

Use a manual segue ("triggered segues") in the storyboard instead of using your current Button segue. Give this segue an identifier (for example "LoginSegue") and start the segue manually in your Button Action function:

```
if (*password ok* && *email ok*) {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"LoginSegue" sender:nil];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender
```

in your view controller. You do your validation there, and if it´s OK then return YES; if it´s not the return NO; and the prepareForSegue is not call.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.